# How to get the dynamic image title from wordpress from "get_the_post_thumbnail" function?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, responsive-images

I am learning to code and while developing a test website I liked the way below code snippet worked to have more control and print responsive srcset images. The only thing missing is How can I get the dynamic title which I add inside the wordpress media upload to show on the front end as a result of the code.

Please note that the below snippet prints the alt tag from the image correctly, However, title is not showing...

```
<?php
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'large', array('title' => '', 'sizes' => '(max-width: 480px) 480px, (max-width: 640px) 512px, (max-width: 960px) 960px, (max-width: 1280px) 480px, '));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use get_post & pass the ID of the thumbnail & get the title from the object.

```
echo get_post($post->ID)->post_title;
echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_title;
```